# KivyMD application - How to add another screen

Tags: python-3.x, kivy-language, kivymd

I am a newbie Python developer, and I need help with this, especially KivyMD.

My issue is that currently I made an opening screen for my application but I want to be able to switch between different screens as well. I'm not sure how to implement that and I would be grateful if someone assists me. I have a button at the MainApp Screen that is leading to another function but I have no idea how to switch/create another screen. Please, assist me.

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    password_list = ()
    username_list = ()
    username_input = ()
    password_input = ()
    password_input_confirmation = ()
    email_input = ()

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Amber'  # theme color
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = '900'  # theme hue
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'  # theme mode
        screen = Screen()
        self.username = Builder.load_string(username_field)  # username field
        self.password = Builder.load_string(password_field)  # password field
        submit_button = MDRectangleFlatIconButton(text='Log In', icon="login-variant",
                                                  pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3},
                                                  on_release=self.login_test)
        submit_button2 = MDRectangleFlatIconButton(text='Registration', icon='account-box',
                                                   pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.22},
                                                   on_release=self.registration_screen)
        logo_image = Image(source="logowe.png", pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.75})
        arr = MDLabel(text='2022 Anaconda 1337. All rights reserved.', pos_hint={'center_x': 0.86, 'center_y': 0.05}, font_style='Caption')
        screen.add_widget(self.username)
        screen.add_widget(self.password)
        screen.add_widget(logo_image)
        screen.add_widget(arr)
        screen.add_widget(submit_button)
        screen.add_widget(submit_button2)
        return screen

    def login_test(self, text):
            print(self.username.text)
            print(self.password.text)
            try:
                cur.execute('SELECT USERNAME from VoyagerKV_reg')
                self.username_list = [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]
                print(self.username_list)
                self.username_verified = ()
            except Exception:
                pass
                if self.username.text in self.username_list:
                    self.username_verified = self.username.text
                    print("Verified Username - " + self.username_verified)
                else:
                    pass
            try:
                username_test = self.username_verified
                cur.execute("SELECT PASSWORD FROM VoyagerKV_reg WHERE USERNAME = %s", [username_test])
                self.password_list = [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]
                print(self.password_list)
            except Exception:
                pass
                if self.password.text in self.password_list:
                    self.password_verified = self.password.text
                    print("Verified PW - " + self.password_verified)
                else:
                    pass

    def registration_screen(self):
        pass
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: I want to input a KivyMD ScreenManager into this code. The functions under MainApp are my first screen. First, I would like to transfer these functions to another class. I want to keep class MainApp() clean and last but not least I want to add another Screen associated with another class. I am really confused and have no idea how to set up this.

Comment: It's sometimes almost impossible to find any solution without even reproducing the actual problem you are facing. Here you haven't included the kv strings. However to switch between screens you can use method [`switch_to`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.switch_to) or attr. `current`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).